# Multiplying surface equation by -1 gives different gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis, 3d

So while trying to find the gradient of the surface given by the equation

x+y=5

The gradient was <1,1,0>

And then I multiplied both sides of the equation by negative 1 giving me

-x-y=-5

The gradient became <-1,-1,0>

So the gradient changed although it is the equation of the same surface... so why is that or do I have some misconception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient will give you the direction of greatest increase of the objective function, which in this case is $$f(x,y,z)=x+y-5$$ and your surface is $f=0$. (You could define $f$ in many ways to give this same surface, this is just an example way).

The second case you mention is when the objective function is now $$g(x,y,z)=-x-y+5,$$ so naturally the gradient of $g$ will point in the opposite direction to that of $f$, as we would now need to decrease $x$ and $y$ to increase the value of $g$.

So the gradient of a surface can be slightly ambiguous, and some care is needed to define what we mean by 'increase'.

Comment: What if I'm using the grad to find the perpendicular to a surface to use it in stokes theorem and the equation of the surface is given to me as z=9-x-y

when i find the grad should i go  for grad(z+y+x) or grad of(-x-y-z)

Comment: In general, Stokes theorem and its forms require the outward-pointing normal to a surface (e.g. the divergence theorem). If the question you are answering has any sort of 'sense' of interior or exterior then you need to make the appropriate choice of inside or outside. In many cases, however, both normals are equally 'good', and you must simply be consistent throughout your work to ensure that no mistakes occur. Do you have the exact question that you're being asked?

Comment: The question is: Given the vector function F=<3z,4x,2y>  The surface S is part of the paraboloid z=9-x^2-y^2 with z>=0 and C is the trace of S on the xy plane.... find Integration of F.dr using Stokes theorem......

So in this example which normal to the surface is outward/ should be taken

Comment: Are you supposed to integrate around C? In which case the 'dr' that you choose will tell you which normal to use, following the right hand rule (see the Wikipedia page for stokes theorem for a good explanation).

Answer (score 1):

You are changing you coordinate system when you multiply by $1$. For example, the direction of increasing $x$ reverses. So in the new coordinate system the gradient will have opposite sign.

The transformation
$$
x\to -x \qquad y \to -y
$$
is a coordinate system inversion, a reflection through the origin. Your image is now upside down.

Comment: What if I'm using the grad to find the perpendicular to a surface to use it in stokes theorem and the equation of the surface is given to me as z=9-x-y

when i find the grad should i go  for grad(z+y+x) or grad of(-x-y-z)